# eclipse wrong VM related to java 1.7

Tags: macos, java, eclipse

So I have been searching for hours on this.

So I installed java 1.7 on my mac before I realized I wanted/needed to use 1.6. I have managed to change everything so that the command line sees version 1.6. My issue is that whenever I try to compile something in eclipse it is saying "Specified VM install not found: type MacOS X VM, name Java SE 7 [1.7.0_45]"

I tried to reinstall 1.7 to see if that would fix things. It hasn't.

I am in OSX 10.8

EDIT:

The solution for now was to blow away my workspace and check everything out again

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is not good at updating its configuration :). go ahead and check for the right JRE in the following spots:

- Eclipse global preferences (Eclipse preferences > Java > Installed JREs)
- Project properties > Libraries

I had the same problem using ant build. The way to fix it there is by going to Run > External Tools > External tools configurations... and adjusting the JRE on the JRE tab

Answer (score 0):

Look in `Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` to see what JREs Eclipse knows about. You can add and remove JREs here.

Comment: This is set to JRE 1.6 but when I run my ant build file it is still giving me the error concerning running the 1.7 VM

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used ant build. The problem was in the "External Tools Configuration...". The JRE was set to 1.7.45, which no longer existed.